# Theorem title formatting

Tags: theorems

I want to display a theorem title, it is simple:

```
\begin{theorem}[Name]
```

I get

```
Theorem 4.5 (Name).
```

but I don't like the dot at the end. I want it to look like this:

```
Theorem 4.5. (Name)
```

Can you help me with that?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) It would be best if you could provide a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) in particular, please include the packages you use to create your theorems (`amsthm`?, `thmtools`? `ntheorem`? `other`?). Welcome!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `amsthm` package allows you to define custom theorem styles, with custom heading specifications.  To get the formatting you desire, you can define a new style, say `custom`, and then declare a `theorem` environment using that style.  Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

% Create a `custom` theorem style.
\newtheoremstyle{custom}
  {\topsep}   % Space above
  {\topsep}   % Space below
  {\itshape}  % Body font
  {0pt}       % Indent amount (empty value is the same as 0pt)
  {\bfseries} % Theorem head font
  {}          % Punctuation after theorem head
  {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt} % Space after theorem head
  {\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}.\thmnote{ (#3)}} % Theorem head spec

% Create a `theorem` environment using the `custom` style.
\theoremstyle{custom}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Name]
This is the new theorem environment.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```